# Impute Continuous Predictor which 0 or median is not an option

Tags: r, regression, data-imputation

I have a dataframe of the following patients:

```
PatientID       Days.To.Develop.Symptoms
1               0
2               1
3               3
4               NA
```

As you can see above, patient 4 did not develop symptoms. It logically incorrect to impute Days.To.Develop.Symptoms with 0 or the median since the patient never developed symptoms. My model (Logistic Regression with LASSO regularization using glmnet) does not accept NA. What is an appropriate method to solve this problem?

Note: The outcome of the algorithm is binary (Acute Kidney Injury vs. Not Acute Kidney Injury). There is a total of 210 predictors inputted in the model that are categorical and continuous.

Comment: So is this survival analysis then? I think LASSO has an option for that.

Comment: What are you predicting?

Comment: It is a phenotyping algorithm to identify patients with kidney injury. Other predictors exist that are continuous and categorical.

Comment: In this one instance, it may make sense to say the median is 2 (average of 1 and 3) with NA the 'largest'. But more generally, this has to do with 'censored' data, and you may want to read about various kinds of censoring in your text or online.